# Flex lexer modifying constant in output .lex.c file

Tags: c, arduino, flex-lexer, lexer, flash-memory

I'm working with flex to generate custom language. I'm wondering if there is a possibility to add in some way a setting that will change a part of generated .lex.c file.
Namely, a part of code which flex generates is an array in yy_accept, in my case with ~1500 elements:

```
static const flex_int16_t yy_accept[1453] =
{   0,
  122,  122, ...
```

I want to set certain variables generated automatically to be stored in FLASH memory of my arduino board. For example there are libs in C which force variable to be stored in FLASH, resulting in something like:

```
FLASH static const flex_int16_t yy_accept[1453] =
{   0,
  122,  122, ...
```

Now I need to change it manually everywhere I want. Can it be done automatically with some options? Or maybe it's possible to redirect all variables into FLASH?

Comment: IIRC `flex` uses a template source file with special markers in it, and `flex` replaces the markers with its auto-generated code. You could take this template, add the `FLASH` macro before the markers in the right place, and tell `flex` to use your template instead of the standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: that should work, but there's a small subtlety: the template file is actually compiled into the flex executable. So it might not be present in the filesystem, or it might be different from a file with the expected name. You can supply your own template file, but to create it you'd probably want to start with the one actually used by your version of flex. Flex is open source, so you can  download the template file from the repository, but you need to make sure you have the right version.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: actually, no, now that I remember better. I did this once and it was a pain. The flex build runs flex.skl through m4 before baking it into an executable. So you can't just use `flex.skl` as the basis for your modified template; you need to use the one which has been m4'd. (M4 is run again after code generation. See the comments at the top of the skeleton file .)

Comment: @rici Fair enough, it's more complicated than I thought (well, I haven't been using flex for quite a few years, nowadays I hand-code my lexers, and parsers :) ).

Comment: As another possible workaround, you could add a post-processing step once the flex file have been generated, and let it pass through `sed` (or similar tool) to search for the arrays and add the `FLASH` macro in front of their definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some research and multiple tries I've sticked to sed editor and added post processing as a command in make file, so this is sample solution:

```
sed -i "s/static const/FLASH static const/g" "myFile.cpp"
del sed* /a /s
```

2nd line removes temp file created by sed.